# SLURM add nodes to suspended job

Tags: slurm

Is there a possibility to add nodes (cores) to the suspended jobs ?
As an example:
scontrol update jobid= then something to accomplish the task

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
 Wahi

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of a *suspended* job is not possible, regarding the Slurm [documentation](http://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#job_size). Only *pending* and *running* jobs.

> Job(s) changing size must not be in a suspended state...

Hope it helps!